# URLs ending with a question mark (?) spring

Tags: html, spring, jsp, url

I get url such as "http://localhost:8080/user/allUsers?"
how can I delete a question mark from there ?

My controllers is :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user")
     public class UserController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/allUsers**")
public ModelAndView allUsers(){
    ModelAndView model= new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("allUsers");
    return  model;
}  }
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of what do you want to do ?

Comment: I want that my urls be without a question mark at end

Comment: therefore if a user get this url : "http://localhost:8080/user/allUsers?" , you wish user redirecting at "http://localhost:8080/user/allUsers", that's it ?

Comment: yes , that's right

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put into your method `HttpServletRequest request`, and then analyse if there are some query. Indeed generaly, in the urls, all characters after a question mark is identify as a paramater so ???? involve that ??? is a paramater. Your method can look like to :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/allUsers**")
public String allUsers(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){
    model.addAttribute("allUsers");
    String queryString = request.getQueryString();
    if (queryString != null && queryString.startsWith("?")) {
        return "redirect:/yourJsp";
    }
    return  "yourJsp";
}
```